# Divide flex column into two rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I've the following columns (Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15420/embedded/result/)
[image: Layout]

The column's same height is achieved with `flex`:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
       .columns-equal {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
    }
}
```

(media used to keep responsiveness)

How can can I divide second column into two rows that fill whole column? e.g.:
[image: Desired]

(I want to make row's content centered)

Is `flex` good approach? I believe I can use table-display, but it brokes the responsiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `col-bordered` elements `display` to `flex` as well and use `flex-flow` of `column nowrap`. Setting `flex` to `1` on the child elements of `col-bordered` will force them to have equal height.

I have also set the `flex` property of `col-bordered` to `0 1 50%` to give them an equal width.

Here is the example.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.columns-equal {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.col-bordered {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.col-bordered div {
    flex: 1;
}

.row-acc-1 {
    background-color: green
}

.row-acc-2 {
    background-color: red
}

.col-bordered {
    border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row columns-equal">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-bordered">
      <span>
        Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-bordered">
      <div class="row row-acc-1">
        <a>Test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-acc-2">
        <a>Test 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, It is what I was exactly looking for.